# Webpack Dev Server (webpack-dev-server) Hot Module Replacement (HMR) Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I have gone through many answers on StackOverflow & on GitHub issues as well but, I am still stuck in Hot Module Replacement in Webpack. I am using `npm start` to run my server with `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline`. **I am trying to change code in my React component, but nothing happens in the browser**.

I am using Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

In my browser `console`, I am getting log messages as

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

But, no hot/live reload is happening. Nothing gets displayed when I change code in my React component file. I was following first video of this tutorial, [Egghead.io/ReactFundamentals](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-development-environment-setup) where everything worked fine.

Following are my package.json & webpack.config.js files.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-fundamentals",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Fundamentals of ReactJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0-rc.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 7777
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It will be great if someone can guide me through this issue as I am not able to proceed further efficiently with the tutorial.

> **Update** I have posted the answer below.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error? Are you accessing the app on port 7777 still?

Comment: Is it a stateless functional component? Is your app running on a vm like vagrant?

Comment: @markthethomas No I am not getting any error. Bundle is valid with this message, "webpack: bundle is now VALID.". And yeah, I am accessing the app on port 7777.

Comment: @azium No I am not using any VM like Vagrant.

Comment: @azium No, it is not a stateless functional component.

Comment: @krishnaxv add `--error-details` to your npm start command. It might help with finding anymore errors with your webpack setup.

Comment: @krishnaxv what is in your `index.html` file?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the solution myself.

I have to run my server with `sudo`. Instead of `npm start`, it has to be `sudo npm start`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I cannot make it work even I use `sudo` in front of `npm start` or `npm run start` but I am sure that the `webpack-dev-server` is already running after running one of the command with or without `sudo`.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for the solution... But I am still curious how did it work.

Answer (score 3):

```
devServer: {
 inline: true, // you missed this line which will reload the browser
 port : 7777
}
```

Comment: I already tried this earlier as suggested in the mentioned tutorial but with no luck. Later I shifted it to `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline`.

Answer (score 3):

Your webpack config is off. Take a look at [react-transform-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate) for a correct setup.

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // or devtool: 'eval' to debug issues with compiled output:
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    // necessary for hot reloading with IE:
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    // listen to code updates emitted by hot middleware:
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    // your code:
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not into `react-transform-boilerplate` as it is experimental now. Also, I want hot/live reloading with **webpack-dev-server** itself without involving `react-hot-loader` plugin as I want to keep it simple as of now. Did you find anything specific which I am doing wrong in my config file? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Once I am able to figure this out, I will definitely try my hands on `react-transform-boilerplate`.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file. And then re-run `npm install`. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following version :
"webpack": "~1.12.14"
 "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1"

And I use following code in app.js in my react.js project.

```
    var webpackconfig =require('./webpack.config');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
    var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

    var http = require('http');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = require('express')();
    var isDeveloping = process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production';
    // var isDeveloping = false;
     console.log("IS developing ",isDeveloping);
   var serverConfig = require('./globalconfig.js')

   var serverPort = serverConfig.port

   app.get('/css/bootstrap.min.css', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,           'public/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
   });



     // swaggerRouter configuration
     var options = {
     controllers: './controllers',
     useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false    // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
     }

     var config = {
      appRoot: __dirname // required config
      }


     // Start the server
     app.listen(serverPort, function () {
       console.log('Your server is listening * on port %d        (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
});


     if (isDeveloping) {
        app.use('/node_modules', express.static('/node_modules'));
        app.use(express.static('src/web-ui/public/'));
        app.use(express.static('src/web-ui/public/'));
        const compiler = webpack(webpackconfig);
        const middleware = webpackMiddleware(compiler,{
         publicPath: webpackconfig.output.publicPath,
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control" : "public, max-age=604800"
        },
       constentBase:'dist',
       stats:{
         color:true,
         hash:false,
         timings:true,
          chunks:false,
         chunkModules:false,
         modules:false
       }

      });
      app.use(middleware);
      app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
      app.get('/',function response(req,res){
                         res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(_dirname,'dist/index.html')));
       res.end();
       });
    } else {
       app.use('/node_modules', express.static('/node_modules'));
       app.use(express.static('dist/public'));
       app.use(express.static('dist'));

       app.get('/', function response(req, res,next) {
         console.log("Processing req");
         var entryFile = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html');
          console.log("Hitting the Root",entryFile);
          res.sendFile(entryFile);
        });
       }
```

Same code get hot replaced on other employees computer,but not always,but many times hot replace won't work in my computer.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your module loader to this:

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel"],
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: react-hot-loader is deprecated

Comment: He had it listed in his dependencies.